# bukalapak.com login using php curl

Tags: php, curl, nginx, cookies

im using curl to login at bukalapak.com .
but always redirect "you are being redirected" & i solve it  use curl followlocation true, but why not loged in after redirect?
help me & thanks before

```css
<?php
function curl($url, $post){
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl,
array(CURLOPT_URL => $url, //put your url here
CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => false,
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
//CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
CURLOPT_POSTREDIR => 3,
CURLOPT_HEADER => true,
//CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
//CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
//CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
CURLOPT_POST => true,
CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => false,
CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE => "cookie.txt",
CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR => "cookie.txt",
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $post,
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
"cache-control: no-cache",
"Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8"
),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$info = curl_getinfo($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);
curl_close($curl);
return $response;
}

$p = array(
"user_session[username]"=>"Myuser@gmail.com",
"user_session[password]"=>"Blablabla",
"commit"=>"Login",
"comeback"=>"%2F"
);

$login = curl("https://www.bukalapak.com/user_sessions", http_build_query($p));

echo $login;
?>
```

```css
HTTP/1.1 302 Found Server: nginx Date: Fri, 03 Feb 2017 06:28:03 GMT Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8 Location: https://www.bukalapak.com/ Transfer-Encoding: chunked Connection: keep-alive Status: 302 Found Cache-Control: max-age=0, private, must-revalidate, no-transform X-We-Need-To-Talk: Hey, you need to check out https://www.bukalapak.com/careers :) Vary: Origin X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies: none X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block X-Request-Id: 90f9ca9a-4ade-4c3d-a0ea-592effd5c2ee X-Download-Options: noopen X-Found-Something: Found any vulnerabilities in our system? https://www.bukalapak.com/bug_reports X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff Set-Cookie: _mkra_ctxt=8891a37006424c9c608a41bf3f6558de--302; path=/; max-age=5; HttpOnly Set-Cookie: lskjfewjrh34ghj23brjh234=RjhGMUlkUEpHb0NOaTNLeUFoT2x2RmxZeWxDTWRySEV6aUc4a0tBOWhqbGdZVS9kWUlOZHFOSXNVZWt2UmJCTkFBRXZLVW8wd21rUktrYXZQR05lUU01aHRuemdzVi91WnFqcUFid2s0MVhUbGhmQXk0cGIrVU5iaXR3UW1HQ21LeHJHRHhMRGZucGo3UUluZ2FLbjJMSWZiZVExODgyRmtUQXJaMTZjYVQxMXZSOWg5U3FGeHZZTGdxVllNTFp4MGtDcnJiaEEwL0NkTVNNT2lTWE8yQXNtNEIzWTVKc0h4NVdVeEVKYnZMSVFMQ29KcysyUGdnK2VZaWNLaVozL3NXYzVIcXlHWkY4SDZESjF4RXp6ak5wVXVOeXRXdjZ0YkZ1UWhPQVJNcjA9LS1od2k3aTgzM3pBSEx5TDVqcE9ZWUZ3PT0%3D--0f995ca0f739bbb3f94b4e92b6628da326a2cb5c; domain=.bukalapak.com; path=/; HttpOnly Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains You are being redirected.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first off, to login, you need a valid cookie session id and "authenticity_token" combo. each cookie session has its own unique authenticity_token , and if you don't post the correct 1, you won't be able to log in.

your code makes no attempt to attain an authenticity_token.

you are also missing a bunch of login parameters, which might make login impossible. to mention a few, `utf8`, `comeback`, `ab_keep_login` and `commit` (and there's more)

also, your code use `multipart/form-data` encoding, but the website use `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` encoding, so fix that (use http_build_query to generate a valid x-www-form-urlencoded string)

first make a GET request to the login page, make sure cookies are enabled, parse out all the `<input>` tags that belong the the login request (but warning, there are several forms in the html containing `<input>` tags, you only want the inputs belonging to the login form, aka id `new_user_session`), their names and values (use DOMDocument for that), modify the username/password variables, and send the login POST request with all those tags, and make sure to use `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` encoding (aka what `http_build_query` gives you), just like a real browser does.

using hhb_curl from https://github.com/divinity76/hhb_.inc.php/blob/master/hhb_.inc.php , here's an example (it should work, provided a real username/password)

```
<?php
declare(strict_types = 1);
require_once ('hhb_.inc.php');
$hc = new hhb_curl ();
$hc->_setComfortableOptions ();
$hc->exec ( 'https://www.bukalapak.com/user_sessions' );
$html = $hc->getResponseBody ();
$domd = @DOMDocument::loadHTML ( $html );
$inputs = array ();
foreach ( $domd->getElementById ( "new_user_session" )->getElementsByTagName ( "input" ) as $input ) {
    $inputs [$input->getAttribute ( "name" )] = $input->getAttribute ( "value" );
}
var_dump ( $inputs );
assert ( array_key_exists ( 'authenticity_token', $inputs ) );
$inputs ['user_session[username]'] = 'Myuser@gmail.com';
$inputs ['user_session[password]'] = 'Blablabla';
$hc->setopt_array ( array (
        CURLOPT_POST => true,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query ( $inputs ),
        CURLOPT_URL => 'https://www.bukalapak.com/user_sessions',
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array (
                'Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8' 
        ) 
) );
$hc->exec ();
$html = $hc->getResponseBody ();
hhb_var_dump ( $hc->getStdErr (), $hc->getResponseBody () );
```